# Error casting from : weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection...jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: jdbc, casting, weblogic, wrapper

I'm developing web application using Java and oracle database, when i want to test to save the data from web, it shows error like this :

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: {call DFMS.USP_PC_AFTER_SUBMIT(   ?,   ?,   ?,   ?   )}
### Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Firstly, i think it was because of the environment DEV server and UAT server, but i compared everything, and it has no differences between the servers.

And then, i try to test from my Local server using UAT database, and it works.
I've try to search the same error in search engine and it has results but no answers.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already know the answer, just delete your ojdbc from your lib!